# Getting the name of fields which contain @NotNull annotations

Tags: java, collections, annotations, java-stream

I want to get the names of the field which contain @NotNull in as the annotation in their entity definition.

```
@Entity
public class student{
 @NotNull
 private Integer sid;
 @NotNull
 private String sname;
 private Integer age;
}
```

I created the following functions

```
public boolean hasNotNull() {
            return Arrays.stream(this.getClass().getDeclaredFields())
                    .anyMatch(field -> field.isAnnotationPresent(NotNull.class));
        }

public List<String> getValue() {

        if (hasNotNull()) {
            Stream<Field> filter = Arrays.stream(this.getClass().getDeclaredFields())
                    .filter(field -> field.isAnnotationPresent(NotNull.class));
            filter.forEach(obj -> obj.getName()).collect(Collectors.toList());      }

        else
            return null;
    }
```

The error says

> *Cannot invoke collect(Collectors.toList()) on the primitive type void*

I am new to java 8 concepts and streams as well.
Please suggest

Comment: Remove the `.forEach(obj -> obj.getName())`. Or change it to `map` if you want to collect the field names. Besides that, there’s no point in splitting this simple single chain into two parts. Just write a single `Arrays.stream(this.getClass().getDeclaredFields()) .filter(field -> field.isAnnotationPresent(NotNull.class)) .collect(Collectors.toList())` and don’t forget to assign the result to a variable or use a `return` statement, to do something useful with it.

Comment: @Holger But how will I get the name of the field if i did not use obj.getName() ?

Comment: Use `map` to map a stream element to some other value.

Comment: can you please explain it better by sending me the code

Comment: Just replace `forEach` with `map`.

Answer (score 0):

```
filter.map(obj -> obj.getName()).collect(Collectors.toList());      }
```

This will do the required thing